# Breaking vertical scroll in IE and Edge on windows 10

Tags: css, internet-explorer, overflow, microsoft-edge, vertical-scroll

I have a very interesting bug, for which I couldn't find answer. If anyone can help I will be very grateful.

I have two div's

```
   <div id="container" class="container">
        <div class="content"></div>
   </div>
```

They have the following CSS

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 700px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.content {
    width:1500px;
    height:1500px;
    background:#555;
}
```

I have to scroll horizontally the first one with 50px to the left using JS

```
var cont = document.getElementById('container');
cont.scrollLeft = 50;
```

The problem is that if I have `overflow-x:hidden` on the `.container` and I scroll the `.container` horizontally to the left using JS, this blocks the vertical scroll if I try to scroll with the mousewheel... This is happening only in IE and Edge under windows 10

Open the Codepen example under IE and try to scroll the `.container` vertically using your mousewheel.

[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/desig9stein/pen/PjzObo)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is this:

```
cont.scrollLeft = '50px';
```